# Double free or corruption caused by vector

Tags: c++, memory

The destructor for one of my classes (called `Distribution`) is throwing a `double free or corruption` error. When I do a backtrace, I get this:

```
#7  0x0000000000409212 in std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::~vector (
this=0x7fffffff8f70)
at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:351
#8  0x00000000004032c5 in Distribution::~Distribution (this=0x7fffffff8f28)
at Distribution.cpp:165
```

So the error occurs when the `Distribution` destructor finishes and it tries to call the destructor on a vector. It's just a simple vector containing doubles, not pointers or anything. How could `~vector` be causing this error?

ETA: I don't know that I can usefully provide a brief code example here. It happens in several places in my code that all have a lot going on and I don't have a good sense of which parts are relevant. Comments suggest it's a memory corruption issue so I can look for that.

Comment: Just because a program crashes in a destructor doesn't mean that's where the bug is. Welcome to C++. You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: The destructor of vector isn't causing the problem, something else in your code is. Unfortunately you haven't provided much information.

Comment: Often times memory issues don't show up until later.  If you've managed to corrupt something you might not know until you try to release the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a representative MCVE, it's virtually impossible to give a specific answer.

In general terms, the most likely explanation is that some other code (probably called between the constructor and destructor calls for your object, but it could be before your object is even constructed) has invoked undefined behaviour, such as by molesting a pointer.

The effects can be quite indirect.  There is no guarantee that a crash occurs immediately when a bad operation occurs.   In fact, it is quite common for a fault to occur without visible symptom, cause subtle changes of behaviour in unrelated code, and eventually one of those subtle changes results in a bigger malfunction which the operating system can detect - and then it terminates your program.

In your case, some such cascade of events probably has an effect of messing with the workings of your vectors allocator.   That results in a crash in the vector's destructor, despite the cause being in completely unrelated code.

Comment: So does that mean the field storing the vector must be getting accidentally overwritten?

Comment: It could mean that.   It could mean something else.     The result of writing to an invalid address is undefined, and that means there are no defined constraints on what happens as a result.

Comment: Thanks Peter, your comment told me what I needed to know to find the error. Turns out I was in fact overwriting the memory where I was storing a vector.